# How can I check Saturday with date_create()->format('w') in a loop

Tags: php

How can I check Saturday.

```
I tried to do this

    for($j = $date_time ; (int)date_create($j)->format('w') <= 6 ; $j++){
    
    }
```

This error happen.

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a member function format() on bool

When it

```
for($j = $date_time ; (int)date_create($j)->format('w') < 6 ; $j++){

}
```

Somehow it goes well.

How Can I check if $j is Saturday?

```
print_r("date_time");
print_r($date_time);
```

Result is :

```
2022-6-01
```

Comment: Start by showing us what `$date_time` is set to

Comment: Doesn't `date()` already have day of week?

Comment: If you use `<= 6`, then it will match Saturday. The next day of the week is Sunday, ie 0, which is still less than 6. You send it through a loop until it hits 2022-6-32, which of course doesn't exist. - https://3v4l.org/BvNE6